# Repeating same operation for multiple columns of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I'm quite new to python and pandas so I hope I can get some help.

I have a `train_df` that looks like this:

```
  x        y1         y2        y3         y4
0   -20.0 -0.702864  10.392012  1.013891 -8794.9050
1   -19.9 -0.591605   9.450884  1.231116 -8667.2340
2   -19.8 -0.983952  10.240055  0.675153 -8541.5720
```

And an `ideal_df` that looks like this:

```
   x        y1        y2  ...       y48       y49       y50
0   -20.0 -0.912945  0.408082  ... -0.186278  0.912945  0.396850
1   -19.9 -0.867644  0.497186  ... -0.215690  0.867644  0.476954
2   -19.8 -0.813674  0.581322  ... -0.236503  0.813674  0.549129
```

Both have 400 rows.

I want to to sum up the squared deviation (distance) between y-values of `train_df` and `ideal_df` at each given x-value, e.g.:

For the 1st value of x, `y1` from `train_df` and `y1` from `ideal_df`, then `y1` from `train_df` and `y2` from `ideal_df`, etc.

Then repeat the same for every one of the 400 rows of `y1` from `train_df`.

After that, repeat it for `y2`, `y3`, and `y4` of train_df, but that is the easy part.

---

I wrote this

```py
squared_deviations_y1_train = (((train_df.y1)-(ideal_df.loc[:,"y1":"y50"])) ** 2).sum()
```

But I have no idea what I'm doing to be honest.

Comment: Just to clarify; you have two dataframes and you want to calculate the square distance between row `i` in both of them or..?

Comment: Can you list all steps and provide a table with sample expected output for given sample input data? It is hard to understand the ask.

Comment: I edited my question, I think is more clear now.

Comment: @AzharKhan sorry I don't have a sample output. Let's just say for the 1st x value which is "-20.0", I have to calculate  (-0.702864 - (-0.912945)) ** 2 , then (-0.702864 - 0.408082) ** 2, and so on until I calculated all 50 squared deviation (distance) and added them all (sum of the 50). Then I do the same for the second value of x, "-19.9", and so on until I get all 400 rows ( all 400 values of x)

Comment: Yes, @CutePoison, I believe that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge/join the the two dataframes by index and then for each yx column of train_df, compute the squared deviation:

```py
train_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ [-20.0,-0.702864,10.392012,1.013891,-8794.9050], [-19.9,-0.591605,9.450884,1.231116,-8667.2340], [-19.8,-0.983952,10.240055,0.675153,-8541.5720] ], columns=["x","y1","y2","y3","y4"])
ideal_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ [-20.0,-0.912945,0.408082,-0.186278,0.912945,0.396850], [-19.9,-0.867644,0.497186,-0.215690,0.867644,0.476954], [-19.8,-0.813674,0.581322,-0.236503,0.813674,0.549129] ], columns=["x","y1","y2","y48","y49","y50"])

ideal_df = ideal_df.add_suffix("_i")
result_df = train_df.merge(ideal_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left")
for t_col in train_df.columns:
  if t_col != "x":
    result_df[f"{t_col}_sd"] = sum([(result_df[t_col] - result_df[i_col]) ** 2 for i_col in ideal_df.columns if i_col != "x_i"])

[Output]:
      x        y1         y2        y3        y4   x_i      y1_i      y2_i      y48_i     y49_i     y50_i     y1_sd       y2_sd     y3_sd         y4_sd
0 -20.0 -0.702864  10.392012  1.013891 -8794.905 -20.0 -0.912945  0.408082  -0.186278  0.912945  0.396850  5.365406  529.137105  5.911037  3.867627e+08
1 -19.9 -0.591605   9.450884  1.231116 -8667.234 -19.9 -0.867644  0.497186  -0.215690  0.867644  0.476954  4.674201  434.286809  7.737567  3.756179e+08
2 -19.8 -0.983952  10.240055  0.675153 -8541.572 -19.8 -0.813674  0.581322  -0.236503  0.813674  0.549129  8.619554  508.005021  3.091597  3.648075e+08
```